# I made a layout, and sideband or sideline appears don't know why

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

i made a new layout but there are sidebands or sidelines(i mean the scroll lines "when too much content" and you have to scroll a lot" but this side line is on the bottom in google chrome) appears at full viewport dont know why does it happens. if i change the wrap width from 100vw to 90 there will be white space on the right side which is not good.

Here is the image:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrap">
  <div class="el2">header</div>
   <div class="el1">left</div>
   <div class="el3">
     <div class="el5">pakk1</div>
     <div class="el6">pakk1</div>
     phakk
   </div>
  <div class="el4">footer</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>



* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;



}

.el2 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 30vh;
  background: #C2FF76;
}

.el1 {
   width: 20vw;
  height: 70vh;
  background: blue;
  float:left;
}
.el3 {
  float:left;
     width: 80vw;
  height: 70vh;
  background: red;
}
.el4 {

     width: 100vw;
  height: 13vh;
  background: purple;
  float:left;
}
.el5 {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 13vh;
  background: green;
  float:left;
}
.el6 {
    width: 40vw;
  height: 13vh;
  background: green;
  float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hide the overflow on your top-most container this issue will go away.

```
.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

It's good to figure out why you have an overflow though so you can fix the underlying issue.

https://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/

Note: you can also only change the overflow for the X and Y axis

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/

Comment: but Jonathan if it hides all the sidelines i mean the right side i cant scroll down to check the bottom content/footer. I just want to dismiss the bottom sideline not the right side. there are any possibilty for this ? im gonna check that link

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses negative side margins on  some elements, that's what causes your problem.

Just change all the `vw` values to `%` values (same numeric values) - these consider the "real width" of the parent elements.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MopXrq

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was some of the boxes height : vh exceeded the limit.